# TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given in simplefix get method

Tags: python, python-3.x, fix-protocol

I am using simplefix (https://github.com/da4089/simplefix) version 1.0.14. And for some reason I seem to have outdated methods from the library. Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/recapital/Git/tt-fix/client.py", line 59, in run
    self._reader.on_message(msg)
  File "/Users/recapital/Git/tt-fix/message_handler.py", line 31, in on_message
    self.handle_logon(message)
  File "/Users/recapital/Git/tt-fix/message_handler.py", line 39, in handle_logon
    logon.decode(message)
  File "/Users/recapital/Git/tt-fix/tt_messages.py", line 9517, in decode
    if (val := message.get(FIELD_ENCRYPT_METHOD, nth)) is not None:
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here is the code called:

```
def decode(self, message: FixMessage, nth: int = 1):
    if (val := message.get(FIELD_ENCRYPT_METHOD, nth)) is not None:
        self.encrypt_method = EncryptMethod(int(val))
```

And here is the get method in simplefix:

```
def get(self, tag, nth=1):
    """Return n-th value for tag.

    :param tag: FIX field tag number.
    :param nth: Index of tag if repeating, first is 1.
    :return: None if nothing found, otherwise value matching tag.

    Defaults to returning the first matching value of 'tag', but if
    the 'nth' parameter is overridden, can get repeated fields."""

    tag = fix_tag(tag)
    nth = int(nth)

    for t, v in self.pairs:
        if t == tag:
            nth -= 1
            if nth == 0:
                return v

    return None
```

It works if I don't pass the nth parameter, but providing this (that I have to due to repetitions) gives this weird error.

*Edit: 2021.06.23 11:44 CET*

I got it to work by extracting out the message to it's own method:

```
def get_field(message: FixMessage, tag, nth=1):
tag = fix_tag(tag)
nth = int(nth)
for t, v in message.pairs:
    if t == tag:
        nth -= 1
        if nth == 0:
            return v
return None
```

Not sure why the same code works in one place and not in the other.